# Relating rows to one another in separate table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, relationships

I have a table called `Neighborhoods`. Some of these neighborhoods are related, and I'd like to be able to capture that relationship in another table.

For example: NYC's `Union Square` is a neighborhood that's near `East Village`. I want to perform a query for nearby neighborhoods on `Union Square` and get `East Village`. Likewise, I'd like to query nearby neighborhoods on `East Village` and receive `Union Square`.

My plan is to have a table called `NearbyNeighborhoods` that links `neighborhood1` to `neighborhood2`.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: The "brute force" way would be to compute the distance from the center of the neighborhood to the centers of other neighborhoods, but this would involve Haversine.  You could also manually maintain a set of nearby neighborhoods for each one.

Comment: If you give us a precise definition for what makes 2 neighborhoods "near" each other, you might get a precise answer.

Comment: shoot for longitude and latitude, and embrace [geospatial functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html) baked into mysql in recent versions. Here's a hint, make your polygons begin and end at the same coordinate. And, those polygons are defined on the internet, so you don't need to type them in